# XPATH - How to select a value of 1 tag based on the value of other tag

Tags: java, xpath

Here is the XML. Now i want to select all  the /Home/Identifier/HomeNumber values that have a /Home/Coverages/Coverage/Identifier/CoverageName = 'WorkersCompensation' as the value. I ve tried some answers in this forum for similar questions but doesnt seem to work. I need help in constructing the XPATH expression.

```
<Home>
        <Identifier>
          <HomeNumber>1</HomeNumber>
        </Identifier>
 <Coverages>
          <Coverage busStatus="Active">
            <Identifier>
              <CoverageName>PersonalLiability</CoverageName>
            </Identifier>
          </Coverage>
          <Coverage>
            <Identifier>
              <CoverageName>WorkersCompensation</CoverageName>
            </Identifier>
            <Detail>
              <Name>NumberOfInServants</Name>
              <Value>
                <Integer>1</Integer>
              </Value>
            </Detail>
          </Coverage>
         <covergaes>
</Home>
<Home>
.
.
.
</Home>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have almost written it yourself:

```
/*/Home[Coverages
          /Coverage
             /Identifier
                /CoverageName
         = 'WorkersCompensation']
      /Identifier
         /HomeNumber
```

**Note**: I would expect some root element, of course...

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
/*/Home[Coverages/Coverage/Identifier/CoverageName='WorkersCompensation']/Identifier/HomeNumber
```

I'm not a %100 sure if it works or not and I don't really have time to test it.  If it works I'll post an explanation of why I gave this answer later.

Comment: @Dave: I would consider deleting my answer if you say something about this been an **absolute expression**...

Comment: @Dave: this answer is *not* correct -- it selects only a single (or none at all) element, however the OP wants to select many elements. Please, try to understand the remark made by @Alejandro. And do the right thing with your answer.

Comment: @Dimitre and @Alejandro, thank you for pointing out my mistake.  My answer is updated now.